# How do i delete an image in php?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to delete an image in a ajax php file. I have the following code:

```
<?php
define('IS_AJAX', true);   

$id = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['photo_id']);    
$files = $db->query("SELECT * FROM uploaded_photos WHERE id=".$id);        
$files = $files->fetch_object();

$file = $files->path;

if($file){    
unlink("../uploads/".$file);    
$db->query("DELETE FROM uploaded_photos WHERE id='".$id);

}
```

path, in this case, is the image e.g. 1.jpg. It does delete the table row, but it doesn't delete the image in the uploads folder. Hoping someone can help me on this. Thank you beforehand for your efford.

Comment: There are two possible problems: 1. Apache/php doesn't have the correct permission to be able to delete the file. 2. The file name you are passing into the function isn't correct so check the $file variable and make sure that it is correct relative to the working directory

Comment: `unlink` should generate An E_WARNING level error on failure. Do you have corresponding records in log?

Comment: @ Andrew - I checked and the file name is correct. I I don't know if php or apache has the right permission, how can i check this?

Comment: You may want to check that the file is where you think it is with something like `if(is_file($filename = "../uploads/".$file)) unlink($filename); else die('File not found at '.$filename);`

Comment: @Shpionus I don't have an e_warning in the error log.

Comment: Above your define write `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @Rasclatt I tried your script. It didn't die, but it also didn't delete the image from the folder

Comment: Well the file is indeed there if it didn't die. Check the folder and file permissions as suggested by others. You could  try `is_writable()` or `fileperms()`

Comment: @Rasclatt (first of all, thank all of you for your help) I set the file permissions to 777, still, it won't delete

Comment: What is the folder permission? Both have to be writable.

Comment: Try using this code after `$file = $files->path;`: `$pathToFile = realpath("../uploads/".$file);print $pathToFile;exit();` and see if the path is correct.

Comment: If my code doesn't print anything, that means it can't find the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to recheck your code. You have an unclosed Single Quote. See the Code below...

```
        define('IS_AJAX', true);

        $id     = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['photo_id']);
        $files  = $db->query("SELECT * FROM uploaded_photos WHERE id=".$id);
        $files  = $files->fetch_object();

        $file   = $files->path;

        // NOTE THAT if($file) WOULD ALMOST ALWAYS RETURN TRUE SO LONG AS IT CONTAINS ANY STRING
        // HOWEVER file_exists WILL CHECK IF THE FILE PHYSICALLY EXIST ON THE PATH/LOCATION OR NOT.
        // PREFER file_exists IN THIS SCENARIO INSTEAD.
        if(file_exists("../uploads/" . $file)){
            // CHANGE THE FILE PERMISSION ON THE IMAGE SO THAT YOU CAN WORK WITH IT...
            chmod("../uploads/" . $file, 0755);   // <== GIVES YOU PERMISSION TO DEAL WITH THE FILE...
            unlink("../uploads/".$file);
            // BY THE WAY;  HERE IS A PROBLEM... YOU HAVE AN UNCLOSED SINGLE QUOTE AFTER THE EQUAL SIGN.
            // I REALLY WONDER HOW THE TABLE ROW DELETES WITH THE TYPO...
            // TRY REMOVING OR COMPLETING IT THOUGH:        
            //$db->query("DELETE FROM uploaded_photos WHERE id='".$id);   <=== SEE THAT SINGLE QUOTE AFTER "=" THERE? THAT'S YOUR ENEMY.
            $db->query("DELETE FROM uploaded_photos WHERE id=".$id);
        }
```

**UPDATE: WITHOUT COMMENTS**

```
    <?php

        define('IS_AJAX', true);

        $id     = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['photo_id']);
        $files  = $db->query("SELECT * FROM uploaded_photos WHERE id='{$id}'" );
        $files  = $files->fetch_object();       
        $file   = $files->path;

        if(file_exists("../uploads/" . $file)){
            chmod("../uploads/" . $file, 0777); 
            unlink("../uploads/".$file);    
            $db->query("DELETE FROM uploaded_photos WHERE id='{$id}'");
        }
```

Comment: The OP states that the delete from the database works but the file delete does not, despite the extra single quote, which you are correct, should not be there.

Comment: @Rasclatt   You are right... I just also spotted a Typo that made me wonder how the row could delete with such a Typo that could (most probably) generate an error. However; i also suggested that he try a ***var_dump(file_exists($file));*** to see if the File Physically exists or there is an issue with the Path.... ;-)

Comment: @Poiz i tried your code. after trying to delete it, it exit's so you are right. there must be something with the path. How do i find the right path? when i check through ftp the file is in the folder. the uploads folder is located in the httpdocs folder

Comment: @Aurora you need to show your folder structure - where is this AJAX script located and where the image files are located. most probably it's just that your path in the code is wrong

Comment: @Poiz i tried your code. after trying to delete it, it exit's so the path is right because it exists... When i check through ftp the file is in the folder. it just wont delete --this is a correction to my above comment--

Comment: **Great!!!** That is a very good start. It all implies that you might have some permission issues. I updated my code (taking the Permission issue into consideration). You may want to retry the updated code to see what you get...

Comment: @Poiz I retried your code. it doesn't delete the row in the database and the file is still in the folder. so what should i do to fix the permission problem? i already set the uploads folder to 777

Comment: @Aurora  Not just the Uploads Directory alone. Try again the the Code without Comments.... Is it ***Joomla*** that you are using?

Comment: @Poiz THANK YOU - IT WORKS. You, my dear Sir, just made me cry with happiness (no im not using joomla;)

Comment: Just to be clear on this for anybody who reads this in the future, UPDATE: WITHOUT COMMENTS code worked.

Comment: @Aurora  You are kinda cute: and you know that :-) Happy it worked and that you are also Happy too. However, it wasn't me... ***your desire to see it work was the key & thus should be complemented...*** and whosoever assisted in the process is only a channel... so if you say thank you; i'd only smile & think: **...but you are the inspiration...**... what else???   **PEACE!!!**